# Android get image from php server in a secure way

Tags: android

In Android, is there any secure way to download an image from php server in a secure way?
Currently, my android application will get the URL of the image, then get it directly from the URL and bind to the imageviewer.

Thanks

Comment: And what is the issue with this? If you want a secure connection, make sure your website supports HTTPS and fetch the image using that, instead of a HTTP:// url.

Comment: I dont want people know the path of the image (e.g. https://www..../abc.jpg). If I provide the path to the android, people can get the file path through the network detect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a "secure way" but give [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) a try.

Comment: Since, the image loader requires a full path. So it could be a concern that everyone can access the image if get the path

Comment: So you want to load an image without having it's full path anywhere within your Android code?